# Detect when a user control-clicks on a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree

With a Java Swing JTree, is there a way to detect if the user "regular" clicked or control-clicked on a node via a TreeSelectionListener?

Or, detect modifier keys at all, even without that listener interface?  JTrees do handle selection different based on which modifer key the user holds down, but I really want to use that fact in some of the logic in a listener.

Answer (score 1):

no, there isn't. And there shouldn't: the whole point of semantic events (like xxSelection) is to abstract away the lower level (like mouse or key w/o modifier) trigger.

Comment: Well, sure - but semantically, control-select and "regular" select usually mean something different - additive selection vs. replacement selection, for example.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy good point, but not supported in Swing selection listeners

Comment: @kelopatra fair enough; that's what I was afraid of, just wanted to be sure there wasn't a secret way to back out to the InputEvent from the SelectionEvent or some such.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy (too late to edit so here I go with a new comment)  if you describe the requirement at this semantic level - maybe it is supported in TreeSelectionEvent. Never tried and never have seen it used, but there it has a method isNewPath (and a constructor adding a path) - might give you what you need

Comment: the only hocus pocus would be to add a MouseListener and cache the state of the keys on the last mousedown before a tree selection event happened.when the tree select event happened grab the cached value and use that for your logic.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy - don't think that would work, at least not with exploiting unsafe implementation details: selection happens on mousePressed and awtListeners like MouseListeners are notified first-in-first-served. That is a custom mouseListener gets the event after the ui, meaning that the selection change already happened. There's a dirty way out (there alway is ;-) by forcing the custom listener being first in line .. but-a risk.

Comment: @kleopatra ah, ok. i would have thought selection events was on mouseClicked, i guess that makes sense tho as you can change selection while the mouse is down. -- ok, even more lame then -- add a MouseMotionListener and do the same on mouseMoved. -- I agree, the answer is 'no' :)